# How to make these simple?

Tags: c#

I try to copy one form object to another. Following is the repeated setting equal for each textBox and other cotrols. I am wondering if there is any simple way to do these repeated one by one control copy.

```
class CopyLadderAndPlatformWin
        {
            public CopyLadderAndPlatformWin(LadderAndPlatformWin tgLadderAndPlatformWin, LadderAndPlatformWin srLadderAndPlatformWin)
            {
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.chTopPlatform.Checked = srLadderAndPlatformWin.chTopPlatform.Checked;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtIdentifier.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtIdentifier.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtStartAngle.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtStartAngle.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtSizeAngle.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtSizeAngle.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtLadderAngle.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtLadderAngle.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltWidth.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltWidth.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltDatum.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltDatum.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtShellClearence.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtShellClearence.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtGratingWeight.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtGratingWeight.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtLdToDtm.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtLdToDtm.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtHndHgt.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtHndHgt.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtRailWgt.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtRailWgt.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtWnFcCof.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtWnFcCof.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltDpt.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltDpt.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtRailHgt.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtRailHgt.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtHeadStart.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtHeadStart.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtHeadEnd.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtHeadEnd.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltLength.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltLength.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtStrgtWidth.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtStrgtWidth.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltAngle.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltAngle.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltOffset.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtPltOffset.Text;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtTopDatum.Text = srLadderAndPlatformWin.txtTopDatum.Text;
                
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.rdApplyWind.Checked = srLadderAndPlatformWin.rdApplyWind.Checked;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.rdNoWind.Checked = srLadderAndPlatformWin.rdNoWind.Checked;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.chEmpty.Checked = srLadderAndPlatformWin.chEmpty.Checked;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.chTest.Checked = srLadderAndPlatformWin.chTest.Checked;
                tgLadderAndPlatformWin.chLiftWeight.Checked = srLadderAndPlatformWin.chLiftWeight.Checked;
            }
        }
```

I tried follows and call instance as

```
CopyWinform objCopyWinform = new CopyWinform(this, uc2.testedCylinder.frmCylinderDimensions);
```

After one loop of iteration, it jumps out in following method.

```
class CopyWinform
{
    public CopyWinform(Form tgForm, Form srForm)
    {
        foreach (Control src in srForm.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control dst in tgForm.Controls)
            {
                if((src is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox) && (dst is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox))
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)src).Name == ((CheckBox)dst).Name)
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)dst).Checked = ((CheckBox)src).Checked;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ((src is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox) && (dst is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox))
                {
                    if (((TextBox)src).Name == ((TextBox)dst).Name)
                    {
                        ((TextBox)dst).Text = ((TextBox)src).Text;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ((src is System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton) && (dst is System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton))
                {
                    if (((RadioButton)src).Name == ((RadioButton)dst).Name)
                    {
                        ((RadioButton)dst).Checked = ((RadioButton)src).Checked;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes there are better ways but why do you need to do that? What is the requirement?

Comment: I need to transfer the saved values of controls to another form to be displayed (re-play).

By the way, the codes above are working well. But, it is stupid repeating each same type/name control. I am trying to use a simple foreach in lieu of so many lines . But I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @JohnWang if the code works then this may be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. But, I need a simple iteration way to replace this highly repeating kind of copies, say no more 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all controls on the source form in one loop.

Within this loop write another loop to iterate through controls on the target form.

Compare controls by Name.

When name matches copy value from source to target depending on control type.

Here is the code that demonstrates the idea:

```
foreach (var src in srLadderAndPlatformWin)
{
    foreach (var dst in tgLadderAndPlatformWin)
    {
        if (dst.Name != src.Name)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (src is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox)
        {
            dst.Checked = src.Checked;
        }

        // Add more winforms control type specific rules here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your codes. I tried the same way. But it does not work. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnWang Could you be more precise?

Comment: tgLadderAndPlatformWin and srLadderAndPlatformWin are two (2) objects of WinForm LadderAndPlatformWin. I want to copy all control inputs such string in TextBox, check or uncheck in Radio Button  and etc. of object srLadderAndPlatformWin to object tgLadderAndPlatformWin.

Comment: @JohnWang necromancing three (3) years old post :) That's what code above is doing. just add other control types specific code where I said `// Add more winforms control type specific rules here`

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you said:

> I need to transfer the saved values of controls to another form to be displayed (re-play).

The correct way to do this is to have a class that represents the thing you are manipulating or displaying in the first form. For example, let's say you are manipulating or displaying a thing called `Platform` (by looking at your code).

You need to create a class for your `Platform` like this:

```
public class Platform
{
    public double LadderAngle { get; set; }
    public int LadderWidth { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

Then create an instance of that in you first class and work with that instance, like this:

```
var platform = new Platform();

// This can fail so use TryParse but I will just use Parse for brevity
platform.LadderAngle = int.Parse(tgLadderAndPlatformWin.txtLadderAngle.Text);
```

Then, instead of copying values from controls to other controls, simply pass that object reference to your 2nd form:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Platform = platform;
```

For that to work, you need to create a property in your 2nd form like this:

```
public Platform Platform { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy only `Text` and `Checked` properties,
You can use reflection to iterate over all properties off `LadderAndPlatformWin` and check if they have a property with checked or text value and then copy values.

Code will be like this:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void DoCopy()
    {
        var source = new SomeObject();

        var Destination = new SomeObject();
        Destination.A = new AnotherObject();
        Destination.C = new LastOne();
        Destination.B = new AnotherObject();

        var type = source.GetType();
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(flags);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var insideSource = property.GetValue(source);
            var insideType = insideSource.GetType();

            var insideDestination = property.GetValue(Destination);


            insideType.GetProperties(flags).Where(s => s.Name == "Text" || s.Name == "Checked").ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                p.SetValue(insideDestination, p.GetValue(insideSource)); 
            });

        }

        Trace.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Destination));
    }

    public class SomeObject
    {
        public AnotherObject A { get; set; } = new AnotherObject() {Text = "Text"};
        public AnotherObject B { get; set; } = new AnotherObject() {Text = "Text2"};

        public LastOne C { get; set; } = new LastOne() {Checked = true};
    }

    public class AnotherObject
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastOne
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }
```